# Error while using rjson package to retrive Yahoo's API Stock data

Tags: r, api, yahoo, yahoo-finance, rjson

I'm trying to get SPY prices from Yahoo real-time API, the code used to work in the past but now I get this error (below), How can I overcome this problem

```
library(rjson)    
    json_file <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SPY/quote?format=json&view=detail"
    json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
    json_data
```

I get this error:

```
"Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/AA/quote?format=json&view=detail': HTTP status was '406 Not Acceptable'
```

Comment: I get the same error. It is likely they have moved the API endpoint from when you last ran your code. I noticed there is a Yahoo finance tag.  You may want to check there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL as an alternative. It downloads a CSV format but can be parsed easily. http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG+APPL&f=nl1r